# What are the list of SAP function modules to call using SAP java connector?

Tags: java, python

For example:

TH_USER_LIST – Displays users logged onto SAP Server

NOTE: I want to monitor the Sap System using JCo so that I need all the function modules to call from JCo.
Especially I want function modules to get
*List of Alerts in Sap System
*List of Worker Processes with those Status
*List Of BackGround jobs
*List Of server Instaces
and e.t.c

Comment: How about the SAP System Monitoring Mobile App? http://www.sap.com/pc/tech/mobile/software/lob-apps/it-system-monitoring/index.html

I guess it does everything you need from a central point of view via Solution Manager. Install it and you could connect to the same Odata services on Gateway to build your own user interface.

Comment: The other approach is to execute each transaction you are interested in and review the code.

Comment: Dear Mikael I need to develop a sap monitoring software .So If you know function modules please list Out in sap performance and diagnostics point of view.

Comment: Why would anyone want to build a new monitoring software? What's the business reason? There is a ton of monitoring already available at every SAP customer. I would ask the hosting team for any notification needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jobs, you will find everything you need starting with "BAPI_XBP_JOB*". Other useful modules starts with "TH_*".